# Changing leaflet markers to circleMarkers

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to Change Leaflet markers to circleMarker on data coming from geoJSON file.

Until now her is how I display data on map:

```
const geodesic = new L.Geodesic().addTo(map); /* Affiche les ligne géodésiques*/
geodesic.fromGeoJson(waypoints);

function pointFilter(feature) {
if (feature.geometry.type === "Point") return true
}

var points =  new L.geoJson(waypoints, {filter: pointFilter}).addTo(map);
```

My geoJSON file contains LineStrings and Points.

The geodesic lines and standard icon markers are displayed, but I would change them by circleMarker between each lines.

Hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks
Pierre

Comment: In the examples you have an exact example [geojson](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/)

Comment: I tried This without success:

   ``var points =  new L.geoJson(
  waypoints, {
   pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
 {filter: pointFilter}}).addTo(map);``.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code may look like, change it as you see fit.
Here'a a whole example - [autocomplete-with-geojson](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#64.autocomplete-with-geojson)

```js
const geojsonlayer = L.geoJSON(object, {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {
      color: feature.properties.color || "red",
      weight: 7,
      opacity: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
    };
  },
  pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
    if (feature.properties.type === "Point") {
      return new L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: 20,
      });
    }
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {},
});
```

Comment: Insert a working example here https://codepen.io/

Comment: I forgot: 
pointToLayer: function (feature....

Thanks a lot for help.